# Encryption for EBS Volume with ElasticBeanStalk and without

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, volumes

there. I've been planning to encrypt my EBS volumes running my production application. Here are the steps, I have decided to consider before encrypting the volumes for my elasticbean environment running behind the load-balancer.

1. Increasing the number of minimum instances to exact double of current value.
2. Enabling default encryption from EC2 dashboard.
3. Changing the termination policy to oldest instance first.
4. Once, new volumes are created, tested successfully.
5. Changing back the minimum instance value.

Firstly, how would I be sure that the load-balancer is directing the traffic to my new encrypted instances?
Secondly, what can be expected downtime, I know when Load-Balancer goes for health checks, and it fails, it redirects, I want it to keep the traffic divided among the number of instances so everything gets tested.